# Ajax call to JSON service isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'll admit my exposure to JQuery / Ajax has been somewhat limited thus far, I am attempting to get JSON data from two web services:

http://w.xaviertidus.com/Json.svc/getInServiceTransponders

http://w.xaviertidus.com/Json.svc/latestTransponderUpdates

Using the following code:

```
function fetchTransponderData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://w.xaviertidus.com/Json.svc/getInServiceTransponders",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function fetchFarcsData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://w.xaviertidus.com/Json.svc/latestTransponderUpdates",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately it keeps throwing an error (the alerts under 'error' in the ajax statement fire) and not giving me detail, i have used fiddler and it is making a request to the webservices and going to them myself yields expected JSON results.

Can anyone shed any light on this problem for me? Many thanks!

Comment: Look at your JavaScript error console, detail should be there.

Comment: there are no details in the error console, or if I use FireBug

Comment: What is the hostname in the URL of the HTML document you are running this in?

Comment: javascript is located at http://farcs.xrnd.com.au and the web services are located at http://w.xaviertidus.com

Comment: Then I'm astonished that the JavaScript error console doesn't say `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: This is what I see on the console:  http://w.xaviertidus.com/Json.svc/latestTransponderUpdates Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Meaning, your server is not allowed to access the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a cross domain request. If so you must set the appropriate header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *) or use a proxy server.

Comment: This was the issue, I added the following to my global.asax and all is well now.
`
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JSONP to get around the same origin policy. However, a better option would probably be to call the external site from your server side code and rely on your server to forward that result back to your client.